# After transferring from float type to int type, why the number all altered into -1 in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is the code I entered:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.6,1.2,3.9,4.5, np.nan]})  
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(-1).astype(int)  
for i in df['A']:  
    df["B"] = i  
df
```

But the result I get is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UygwN.png)

So why the column B would all appear as -1 instead of the same as column A?

Comment: Please add the output in code format, not in image.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the entire column to `i` with `df["B"] = i`. In your last iteration, `i` is `-1`, so your entire column `B` is set to `-1`.

If you want to set `B` to `A`, you can just use this (no for loop needed):

```
df['B'] = df['A']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you reassign the entire value of `df["B"]` each time. The last value  in `df['A']` (`np.nan`) when converted to a int is `-1`. Since you are setting `df["B"]` as a whole all the value are assigned as `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for i in df['A']:
    df["B"] = i
```

to

```
for i, item in df['A'].items():
    df.ix[i, "B"] = item
```